# Highcharts 'area' type with normal stacking looks weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to wrap my head around the reason highcharts draws a serrated graph? ( Live data )

Take a look at this fiddle below, it has chart type set to 'area' + normal stacking. ( Forked from the highchart '[Live Data](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)' example )

Using 'stacking: normal' draws a serrated graph.
http://jsfiddle.net/eladchen/4cmz5p2x/5/

```
  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
      type: "area",
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var series  = this.series[0];
          var series2 = this.series[1];

          setInterval(function() {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime();
            var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

            series.addPoint([x, y]);
            series2.addPoint([x, Math.round(Math.random() * 100)])
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    },

        navigator:     {
            enabled: false
        },

        scrollbar:     {
            enabled: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: "normal", // <---
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 6
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Random data',
      data: [
        [1472553132251, 38],
        [1472553133251, 79]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Random data2',
      data: [
        [1472553132251, 338],
        [1472553133251, 179]
      ]
    }]
  });
```

[image: Stacking set to 'normal']

Without 'stacking' http://jsfiddle.net/eladchen/4cmz5p2x/6/

```
 // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
      type: "area",
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var series  = this.series[0];
          var series2 = this.series[1];

          setInterval(function() {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime();
            var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

            series.addPoint([x, y]);
            series2.addPoint([x, Math.round(Math.random() * 100)])
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    },

        navigator:     {
            enabled: false
        },

        scrollbar:     {
            enabled: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },

    plotOptions: {
      series: { // No stacking property <---
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 6
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Random data',
      data: [
        [1472553132251, 38],
        [1472553133251, 79]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Random data2',
      data: [
        [1472553132251, 338],
        [1472553133251, 179]
      ]
    }]
  });
```

[image: Without 'stacking']

Can anyone shed some light as to how 'normal' stacking can be used with a "area" typed chart + live data, Without having the graph look like this?

As far as I'm aware this is not what a graph ( "area" ) with those settings should look like, It should stack them, as it does, except there shouldn't be any white spaces / serrated look to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a curious problem! Since the start of each "serrated" edge on the second (gray) series looked like it was always restarting from null or zero, I tried the `connectNulls` attribute.

This seemed to solve your issue:

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        connectNulls: true  // this will stop the "serrated" appearance
    },
    series: {
        stacking: "normal",
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 6
        }
    }
},
```

Here's a working code snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
      type: "area",
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var series  = this.series[0];
          var series2 = this.series[1];
          
          setInterval(function() {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime();
            var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
            
            series.addPoint([x, y]);
            series2.addPoint([x, Math.round(Math.random() * 100)]);
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    },

  navigator:     {
   enabled: false
  },
    
  scrollbar:     {
   enabled: false
  },
    
  rangeSelector: {
   enabled: false
  },

    plotOptions: {
     area: {
       connectNulls: true // this will stop the "serrated" appearance
      },
      series: {
        stacking: "normal",
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 6
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Random data',
      data: [
        [1472553132251, 38],
        [1472553133251, 79]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Random data2',
      data: [
        [1472553132251, 338],
        [1472553133251, 179]
      ]
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 250px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

I'm not precisely sure **why** this happens, but my guess is that the way area charts are calculated doesn't mesh well with real-time data drawing ... the connection between the new and previous points is getting lost for the series after the first. This doesn't seem be an issue if you were to set `stacking` to `percent`, either.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm aware of these solutions. Nevertheless, I appreciate the time you took on looking into it. If no one will help clarify why this is acting up, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I am copying @GrzegorzBlachliński from Highcharts support to see whether he or his colleagues can answer why this occurs with real-time stacked area charts.

Comment: @elad.chen You may also wish to report this as a bug (since that's what it seems like to me): https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: I will, thanks. btw, I think your mentioning of @GrzegorzBlachliński has no effect while he is not involved in this thread.

Comment: @elad.chen Hmm ... I thought it was a way to flag folks ... I'll do some research on that. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Hi All, this problem looks to be connected with addPoint method. In current code we are adding two points almost at the same time and both times we are redrawing our chart. Even if the current behaviour looks really odd, not redrawing the chart after first addPoint seems to be an answer for the issue. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/r7g4tm5L/1/ We will look closer into the issue.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Great ! that really helps. Thank you both.